# Understanding scam involving mobile transaction number

Tags: credit-card, scam

Today I have received an SMS from the number that my credit card provider uses to send MTANs that have to be entered for e-commerce. So at first the obvious scam seemed to be someone trying to use my credit card for an e-commerce transaction. However checking with the credit card provider they mentioned, that this number is no longer used for MTANs so this SMS was not sent by them (I havent used it in quite a while). What is the gain for the scammer? There is obviously not a real transaction on my card this request is tied to, the SMS has the official format, there is no information where I would have to enter the code, so they can also not get the code from me.

Comment: Given the current security status of the GSM systems, an SMS containing your code can be intercepted, therefore used.

Comment: The weird part is, that the credit card company confirmed in detail, that there was no transaction on the credit card and that they did not issue this MTAN and there is nothing that could be booked using this request. It seems just so strange...

Comment: In that case it's probably just testing/scouting.